# View a pdf file without colour or font-weight?

Tags: pdf

### Situation:

I have a pdf file of a multiple choice exam paper where all correct answers are highlighted in a green colour and the letter is bold (example: a,b,**c**,d).

### General question:

How can I view a pdf file with font-weight and colour removed? Like can I change this in settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No, this can't be disabled in settings.

Longer answer:

The whole point of PDFs is that they look the same no matter where they are viewed since the font/color/formatting info is embedded in the file rather than being rendered. If you want to modify the formatting, you'd have to open the PDF in a dedicated editor application.

Software recommendations are off topic for this site, but a google search for "pdf edit font color" turns up a number of promising options.